# Assigning individual bits to bytes

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, unions, spi

I have a to make a SPI communication between a microcontroller and another chip. The chip accepts a 16bit word. But the abstraction library requires the data to be sent as two 8bit bytes. Now I want to make a wrapper so I can easily create requests for read and write...but I have not yet got any success. Here is how it supposed to be:

The table below shows 16bits. The MSB can be `0` for write or `1` for read. The address can be from `0x0` to `0x7` and the data is 11 bits.

```
R/W  |      ADDRESS   |    DATA
 B15 |      B14-B11   |   B10-B0
 0   |        0000    | 00000000000
 W0  | A3, A2, A1, A0 | D10, D9, D8, D7, D6, D5, D4, D3, D2, D1, D0
```

For example, if I want to read from register `0x1` I think I have to set the bits like this:

```
 W0  | A3, A2, A1, A0 | D10, D9, D8, D7, D6, D5, D4, D3, D2, D1, D0
  1  | 0    0   0   1 |  0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Or reading from register 0x7:

```
 W0  | A3, A2, A1, A0 | D10, D9, D8, D7, D6, D5, D4, D3, D2, D1, D0
  1  | 0    1   1   1 |  0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I have tried to create this struct/union to see if it can work:

```
typedef struct{
    uint8_t acc_mode:1;
    uint8_t reg_addr:4;
    uint8_t reg_data:8; //TODO fix me should be 11
} DRVStruct;

typedef union {
    DRVStruct content;
    uint16_t all;
} DRVUnion;

void DRV_PrepareReadMsg(uint8_t reg, uint8_t* msgBuffer) {
    DRVUnion temp;
    temp.content.acc_mode = 1;
    temp.content.reg_addr = reg;
    temp.content.reg_data = 0; //read mode does not need data!

    msgBuffer[1] = temp.all & 0xFF;
    msgBuffer[0] = temp.all >> 8;
}
```

I am getting strange results...from time to time I get answer from the SPI (I am sure the SPI communication is OK, but my code for preparing messages is the problem).

So the questions are:

- Am I doing the right thing or approach?
- How can I increase bit width of `reg_data` from 8 to 11 without getting compile error?
- What do you suggest for a better approach?

Comment: use uint16_t, can't you then set reg_data to 11 bits?

Comment: I'd recommend *not* using bit fields.  Bit field representation is *entirely* implementation-defined, meaning the order of the bits and what they map to in the underlying data is beyond your control.  You also have to overlap bit fields between two `uint8_t` values, apparently.  No matter what, `uint8_t reg_data:11;` isn't going to work.

Comment: I don't understand why you are tyig to unionize the protocl struct with a uint16_t.  Two uint8_t's would make more sense, eliminating the masking and shifting.  In fact, if I was to do this, I would unionize with msgBuffer, use whatever 'pragma packed' is available from the compiler, and use uint16_t as the the base type for the protocol struct so that the 11-bit field can be accommodated.  That, and be very wary, with much debugging round it to make sure the bits/bytes  were where they should be...

Comment: Is `uint8_t` actually `unsigned char` in your implementation?  It's a platform-dependent hack, but if `uint8_t` actually is `unsigned char`, then you can just cast a `uint16_t *` to `uint8_t *` and not violate strict aliasing since any pointer can always be cast to a `char *`.  That hack may be worth being able to drop all the code needed to handle structures and unions.

Comment: Using `uint16_t` creates the proper types, with an alignment restriction of 16bits. (but I would  prefer *not* using bitfields at all.) You could also keep the bitfields-structure tagless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union {
    struct{     // no struct tag, since it is not needed...
        uint16_t acc_mode:1;
        uint16_t reg_addr:4;
        uint16_t reg_data:11; //TODO fix me should be 11
        } bits;
    uint16_t all;
    uint8_t bytes[2]; //extra bonus when lit;-)
        } DRVUnion;

int main(void)
{
DRVUnion uni,uni13[13];

printf("Size=%zu, %zu\n", sizeof uni, sizeof uni13);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks This works...but when I assign single bytes to `bytes` field I have to do it like this: `instance.bytes[0] = data[1]; instance.bytes[1] = data[0]` and if I just assign to the `all`field it does not work as expected.

Comment: That is because your host and target differ in endianness.