# Changing specific set of bits in a byte

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitmask

I am working on a function that receives a byte and needs to change some of the bits in that byte.

For example, the function receives:

```
11001011
```

Then I need to set the MSB to 0, its easy enough:

```
buffer[0] &= ~(1 << 7);
```

But then I need to set bits **6 through 3** (I refer LSB as bit 0 here) to an argument that gets supplied to the function. This argument can be an integer **from 0 to 6**.

**The important thing is I should not change any other bits.**

I tried with masking and stuff but I failed miserably. Then as last resort I did it painfully like below. It works fine...but it is ugly and generates tons of instructions, making the code run slow:

```
    switch(regAddress) {
        case 0:
            buffer[0] &= ~(1 << 5);
            buffer[0] &= ~(1 << 4);
            buffer[0] &= ~(1 << 3);
        break;

        case 1:
            buffer[0] &= ~(1 << 5);
            buffer[0] &= ~(1 << 4);
            buffer[0] |=  (1 << 3);
        break;

       //YOU GOT THE IDEA!!.....
     }
```

Please let me know hot to do this in one (or two) line of code so I can learn the trick.

I did a mistake, the argument passed is alway 0 to 6, so the MSB of the 4bits that I want to set is always zero, therefore before the switch case I did like:

```
//because we only have 7 address, we already set the 4th bit to 0
buffer[0] &= ~(1 << 6);
```

Comment: Do you mean bits 5 through 3 (since the number 7 only takes up 3 bits), or is the number signed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a bit field, say bits 6 though 3 (four bits total), packed into a value `w` (some type of unsigned integer), then you can set the field with a value `v` with:

```
w = (w & ~0x78) | (v << 3);
```

This assumes that `v` is within the required range.  If not, you can use `(v & 0xf)` in place of `v`.  The mask operation `w & ~0x78` clears bits 6 through 3, the shift operation moves `v` into the proper position, and the bitwise-or operation combines them.

To extract the field from `w`, you can use:

```
(w >> 3) & 0xf
```

The shift operation right-justifies the field, and the mask operation clears the bits outside of the field.  This is equivalent to:

```
(w & 0x78) >> 3
```

This version masks the field before shifting (so it uses a larger mask value).

Make sure `w` has an unsigned type so that the shifts are unsigned.

Note:  This example is for the 4-bit field occupying bits 6, 5, 4, 3.  The `0x78` mask is `((1 << 4) - 1) << 3`, i.e. `0xf << 3`.  The `0xf` mask is `(1 << 4) - 1`.  And the shift amount, `3`, is the number of bits to the right of the field, i.e. bits 2, 1, and 0.

Comment: Given the example, I'm pretty sure the mask should be `0x38`. (i.e. `(((1 << 3) - 1) << 3)`

Comment: I know that was stated, but the code sample clears bits 3, 4 and 5, implying that mask. 6 could have been a typo. 0x34 has bits 2, 4, and 5 set. 0x38 has 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Yes, the code sample isn't consistent, but my answer is for the case of bits 6 through 3.

Comment: It's either `0x78` (in case OP confirms it's 4 bits) or `0x38` (according to OP's code).

Comment: @FlávioToribio Oops, you're right!  I fixed it - don't know how I did that!

Comment: @FlávioToribio Yes it is 4 bits, my mistake, the highest argument will be 6, so the MSB of the 4bits is always 0 (dont care in my case)

Answer (score -1):

Why not loop over the set of bits?

```
def setBits(i, bits):
    for bit in bits:
        i |= 1 << bit
    return i

print(bin(setBits(0b11001011, [3, 4, 5, 6])))
```